# Django: get specific value from queryset

Tags: python, django, dictionary, django-queryset

I´m trying to get the media of sales per month. I can do the calculation but then I can´t get just the value instead a the full queryset.

I found different options and some work in some context but not in other. I guess there is some missunderstanding of different querysets data and dictionaries too.

Here goes my example.

```
 for este in inventario_diferencia:
        este['stock_valor_venta'] = este['existencias'] * este['valor_venta']
        este['diferencia'] = inventario_original.filter(fecha=diferencia_fecha, codigo_kinemed=este['codigo_kinemed']).values()[0]['existencias'] - este['existencias']
        media_venta_mes = Ventas.objects.filter(prod_codigo=este['codigo_kinemed']).values("prod_codigo").annotate(media=Sum("uds")/Count(TruncMonth('fecha'), distinct=True))
```

If a print `media_venta_mes`I get the correct calculation. For example: `<QuerySet [{'prod_codigo': 'TP3 SHOULDER', 'media': 24}]>`

Then I want to insert that `media`  value in the general `inventario_diferencia`dictionary.

If I do `media_venta_mes = media_venta_mes.values("media")` I get `<QuerySet [{'media': 24}]>`.

If I try  `media_venta_mes = media_venta_mes.get("media")`, which works for me in aggregates, I get `too many values to unpack (expected 2)`.

If I try `media_venta_mes = media_venta_mes.media` I get `'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'media'`.

I tryied something more I can´t document now. I know I´m beign a dumb newbie here, sorry and thanks for the help.

**Tests update**

I try `media_venta_mes[0].media` and get `'dict' object has no attribute 'media'`.

I Try `media_venta_mes['media']` I get `TypeError`.

I try `media_venta_mes.first().media`I get `'dict' object has no attribute 'media'`

If I Try

```
media_venta_mes = Ventas.objects.filter(prod_codigo=este['codigo_kinemed']).values("prod_codigo").annotate(media=Sum("uds")/Count(TruncMonth('fecha'), distinct=True)).first()

este['diferencia_mes'] = media_venta_mes.media
```

I get `'dict' object has no attribute 'media'`

If I try `media_venta_mes.first()['media']` I get `'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for 
`media_venta_mes['media']` or `media_venta_mes[0].media`
but I'm not sure I completely understand the question. You may also be looking for the 'first' convenience method:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#first

Essentially, you want to get the first record of the queryset, then get the attribute.

Be careful in trying to set a variable to another with the same name ie: `media_venta_mes = media_venta_mes.media` as you'll have some undesired consequences.

**[EDIT]**

based on your errors, can you try to use
`media_venta_mes[0]['media']`
or
`media_venta_mes.first()['media']`
as that is the typical way to get an element from a dictionary.

**[Edit]**

if `print(media_venta_mes.first())`produces `{'prod_codigo': 'TP3 SHOULDER', 'media': 24}`
but `media_venta_mes.first()['media']` yields `'NoneType' object is not subscriptable` I'm at a loss.

Comment: to set the value in the dictionary it may look like `inventario_diferencia['my_key_value'] = media_venta_mes.first().media`

Comment: could also alter the `media_venta_mes = Ventas.objects.filter(prod_codigo=este['codigo_kinemed']).values("prod_codigo").annotate(media=Sum("uds")/Count(TruncMonth('fecha'), distinct=True))` line and add the first there. So like: `media_venta_mes = Ventas.objects.filter(prod_codigo=este['codigo_kinemed']).values("prod_codigo").annotate(media=Sum("uds")/Count(TruncMonth('fecha'), distinct=True)).first()` then you'd be able to use `media_venta_mes.media` to get the value. To set in the dict: `inventario_diferencia['my_key_value'] = media_venta_mes.media`

Comment: I updated the question after testing your suggestions.

Comment: also what is the output of `print(media_venta_mes)` now?

Comment: If you mean the last option with the `.first()` on the queryset, the answer is: `{'prod_codigo': 'TP3 SHOULDER', 'media': 24}`

Comment: No it didn´t, I added the test to the question